# Using AWS Lambda polling with external SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lambda

I am mostly trying to figure out if what I need is even possible, if someone has pointers as to how, that would be even better.

I have an access key/secret from an organisation I work with, that grants access to an AWS SQS queue (I also have the ARN for that queue). Now I would like to use AWS lambda polling on that queue to execute a lambda function on incoming messages. I fail to figure out how to connect the external SQS with my lambda function. I can put the ARN but then the permissions are missing. I wonder if I can add the access key/secret somewhere or if that is altogether impossible and I have to implement the polling on my own?

Comment: did the answer help? Do you need any further assistance with it? If you made it work please accept the answer to award reputation points. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand it right that the SQS is in one AWS account and your Lambda is in another?

If it's in the same account you should not use static *access* and *secret keys* for Lambda execution. The correct way is to create **IAM Role** with a *Policy* that permits SQS access and execute Lambda with that Role. The *Role* will give it temporary credentials every time it's executed, that's a much more secure option.

This can also be done across accounts - the Lambda IAM Role will allow it to *assume* a role from a different account. But that's a little more involved.

In your case, if the SQS and Lambda accounts are different you can supply the *keys* when opening a connection to **SQS**. If your Lambda is written in Python you can do something like this:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')    # This uses Lambda's IAM Role

sqs_client = boto3.client('sqs',  # This uses the provided SQS credentials
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
)
```

With that you can read from SQS using the provided credentials and write e.g. to S3 using the Lambda IAM Role.

I'm sure other SDKs (e.g. Node.JS) will have a similar capability.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Yep correctly understood.I can obviously implement polling like that myself (which I did by now) but I had hoped to avoid that, because now I need to trigger this lambda via cloudwatch cron events. I would obviously have liked to only execute when there is actually something in the queue. But it seems really not possible.